# Reference to variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I'm try to call a function that I know exists on a variable but for some reason I just can't call in from within the passed function `onUpdate` - Any ideas guys - sorry for the newbness

```
//set up the mirror when view is expanded
function attachMirrorListener(section, mirror) {
    var textarea = document.getElementById(mirror.attr('id'));
    var input = $(mirror.data('input'));
    var myCodeMirror;
    section.click(function() {
        if(section.hasClass('open') && !section.hasClass('mirror-added')) {
            section.addClass('mirror-added');

            input.attr('value','test value!!');
            myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea, {
                onUpdate : function(){ myCodeMirror.save(); //does not work here!!
                    },
            });

        }
        console.log(myCodeMirror);
        myCodeMirror.save(); //works here
    });


}
});
```

UPDATE

I tried rearranging the code, still not working

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var _codeMirror;
    //setup code-mirror
    $('.customize-section').each(function() {
        var section = $(this);
        var mirror = section.find('textarea.wpec-tc-code-mirror');
        if(mirror.length > 0) {
            attachMirrorListener(section, mirror);
        }
    });
    //set up the mirror when view is expanded
    function attachMirrorListener(section, mirror) {
        var textarea = document.getElementById(mirror.attr('id'));
        var input = $(mirror.data('input'));

        section.click(function() {
            if(section.hasClass('open') && !section.hasClass('mirror-added')) {
                section.addClass('mirror-added');
                _codeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea, {
                    onUpdate : codemirrorcallback,
                });

            }
        });
        function codemirrorcallback() {
            _codeMirror.save();
            input.val(escape(textarea.value));
        }

    }

});
```

Here is the error log from the chrome console

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'save' of undefined codemirror.js:26
codemirrorcallback codemirror.js:26
endOperation codemirror.js:1864
instance.(anonymous function) codemirror.js:1871
CodeMirror codemirror.js:95
CodeMirror.fromTextArea codemirror.js:2114
(anonymous function) codemirror.js:19
f.event.dispatch load-scripts.php:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i`

Comment: Does it work if you remove the extra comma after `onUpdate` line?

Comment: Is it possible that the `onUpdate` callback gets called during the actual initialization of `CodeMirror`, so that the assignment to `myCodeMirror` still hasn't taken place? Or do you get the error at a later point? Try to set a breakpoint at the two `myCodeMirror.save()` lines and see which executes first. Also, are you sure you can't reference your `CodeMirror` instance as `this` inside the `onUpdate` callback, so that you can avoid using the `myCodeMirror` reference?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately using this in the onUpdate does not yet have the save() function. I did a `onUpdate : console.log(this); ` and save was not there

Answer (score 0):

The assignment operator works from right to left. So, when you're calling `myCodeMirror.save()` the first time, `myCodeMirror` is still undefined.

```
var myCodeMirror; //undefined

myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea, {
    onUpdate : function() { 
        myCodeMirror.save(); //still undefined 
    }
});
```

You should instead be calling `this.save()` from within the inner onUpdate function.

Comment: Sorry man that technique is not working either. See the error report above